# how to solve array must not contain infs or nans

Tags: python-3.x

```
fa = FactorAnalyzer(rotation = None,n_factors=5)
fa.fit(dat)
print(pd.DataFrame(fa.get_factor_variance(),index=['Variance','Proportional Var','Cumulative Var']))
```

I tried this code and gets the error as array must not contain nulls or infs.

I checked for nulls and infs but there were no nulls or infs shown.
So how can I solve this ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and post the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clean your data set by removing all `nan` and `inf`

```
import pandas as pd

def dataset_cleaner(df):
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame), "df needs to be a pd.DataFrame"
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    keep_indices = ~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)
    return df[keep_indices].astype(np.float64)
```